# Directory structure of Webapp folder in Tomcat

Tags: jsp, tomcat, netbeans

I've developed a JSP project now want to deploy the files on the Tomcat server. I dont want to expose the JSP code so I've also compiled the JSP files from NetBeans.

**Now Where to place the compiled JAVA,class,smap, WAR files** ?

Current directory structure after compilation

```
├───empty
├───generated
│   ├───classes
│   │   └───org
│   │       └───apache
│   │           └───jsp
│   └───src
│       └───org
│           └───apache
│               └───jsp
├───generated-sources
│   └───ap-source-output
└───web
├───css
├───img
├───js
├───META-INF
└───WEB-INF
    ├───classes
    │   └───cms
    └───lib
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to package the web app in a .war file.

Obviously there is no need to include the .java files but only the .class files, they go in WEB-INF/classes. For this you can change the output folder to WEB-INF/classes.
For the .jsp I can't remember but it's probably the same.